An unrecognized screen
I have a laptop and a tower computer. Both computers share two additional externaldisplays with kvm cables. The displays share the same manufacturer and diagonals.
Since Ubuntu 24.04, one of the displays prints the color with that of the laptop. In 24.10, it is black with a white dot. I can't hover over it. The output of the computer display one work but the second one not.
Since the 24.10 update, the mainframe no longer recognizes one of the displays. When I move the output of the computer display between the both, the unreconzied screen move also. If I use one of the two output of the computer display, only the bottom work. In 24.04 the two output of the computer display work.
